# pgfplot height setting does not work when scale only axis is off

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following plot, but no matter what I choose the height to be, it has no effect on the plot height. The only way it works is when I use scale only axis option, but I do not want that. What gives?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3cm,
height=6cm,
footnotesize,
xmin=1,
xmax=15,
xlabel={X},
xmajorgrids,
ymin=0.2,
ymax=1.2,
ylabel={Y},
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={legend cell align=left,at={(axis cs:0.,0.2)},anchor=south}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1c,dashed,mark size=5pt,mark=x,mark options={solid}]
table[row sep=crcr, y expr=\thisrow{Y}*.5]{%
    X    Y\\
    1   1.98396947369363\\
    2   1.86736194644617\\
    3   1.39672685380491\\
    4   1.81801351792524\\
    5   1.65800541448776\\
    6   1.72124859501669\\
    7   1.95053632111296\\
    8   1.5953158074501\\
    9   2.20484922246232\\
    10  2.06660239159798\\
    11  1.15700938093597\\
    12  1.70354273363983\\
    13  1.97071496027903\\
    14  1.5377824362414\\
    15  1.34852389652374\\
};
\addlegendentry{1};

\addplot [color=mycolor3c,solid,mark size=3.0pt,mark=o,mark options={solid}]
table[row sep=crcr, y expr=\thisrow{Y}*.5]{%
    X    Y\\
    1   1.98396947369363\\
    2   1.87985797050402\\
    3   1.81018984587384\\
    4   1.45668153706335\\
    5   1.45662344223124\\
    6   1.42321790298663\\
    7   1.58846550051792\\
    8   1.7261014576169\\
    9   1.84497235618249\\
    10  1.83868784206141\\
    11  1.91262415124094\\
    12  1.87950764557444\\
    13  1.16064983693758\\
    14  1.28630813303169\\
    15  0.729867599135851\\
}; 
\addlegendentry{2};

\addplot [color=mycolor2c,solid,mark size=3.0pt,mark=*,mark options={solid}]
table[row sep=crcr, y expr=\thisrow{Y}*.5]{%
    X    Y\\
    1   1.98396947369363\\
    2   1.58099605261815\\
    3   1.25697492063651\\
    4   1.46582314712387\\
    5   1.3939586089965\\
    6   1.32595119844705\\
    7   1.41440624648194\\
    8   1.53386555109464\\
    9   1.7654715541107\\
    10  1.54694708739791\\
    11  1.53904078916298\\
    12  1.66515096650716\\
    13  1.09210648149942\\
    14  1.2047294527546\\
    15  0.647646671362433\\
};
\addlegendentry{3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: remove footnotesize and try again

Comment: @percusse Thx that worked. Any idea how to make font size small but keep the setting working?

Comment: Switch the order of the options. The `footnotesize` key sets (among other things `height`, so your definition of `height` is overwritten. With `footnotesize,height=3cm`, 3cm should be the one that's used.

Comment: @MobiusPizza, I think TorbjørnT.'s comment answered your question, right? Then we could consider closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Torbjørn T.'s answer worked for me:

> Switch the order of the options. The footnotesize key sets (among
>   other things height, so your definition of height is overwritten. With
>   footnotesize,height=3cm, 3cm should be the one that's used. – Torbjørn
>   T. Sep 9 at 21:10